# SQL Count number of people that do not hold a qualification

Tags: mysql

hoping you can help me as I am going round in circles!

I need to count the number of people that do not hold a certain qualification.

I have tried NOT but this returns all the other qualifications other than the one I wish to count. Whereas I want to specifically count the number of people that do not hold the qualification, i.e. do not have a row entry in the table.

```
SELECT COUNT(tmp.personnelID) AS Number,
        tmp.QualificationID

FROM(SELECT pa.PersonnelID,
            pq.QualificationID 

FROM dbo.PersonnelActive pa
LEFT JOIN dbo.PersonnelQualifications pq ON pq.PersonnelID = pa.PersonnelID
WHERE NOT pq.QualificationID = 125) tmp

GROUP BY tmp.QualificationID
```

Any help you guys can give or point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should count for personnelID that are not in the personnelID with a QualificationID = 125

```
SELECT COUNT(pa.personnelID) AS Num,
        pq.QualificationID

FROM PersonnelActive pa
INNER JOIN dbo.PersonnelQualifications pq ON pq.PersonnelID = pa.PersonnelID
where pa.PersonnelID NOT IN ( SELECT pa.PersonnelID

FROM dbo.PersonnelActive pa
INNER JOIN dbo.PersonnelQualifications pq ON pq.PersonnelID = pa.PersonnelID
WHERE  pq.QualificationID = 125
) 

GROUP BY pq.QualificationID
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately that has not work as it provides me with a list of counted qualifcationID's but not for ID 125.

Comment: Answer  update  .. with inner join for subselect too

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Although your solution did not solve my real world issue (I couldn't release full details) it has pointed me in the correct direction and I have resolved it after 2 days of pulling my hair out!

Thank you :D